# App is running on Android Monitor but not on android

Tags: android, debugging, adb

As I wanted to debug my app, I clicked the Debug button. After this, if I was trying to run the app manually, a message appeared saying "Waiting for debugger to attach...". I turned off and turned on the "Debuggable app" option in the Developer settings and rebooted my phone and this dialog disappeared.

But now when I'm trying to click the Run button in Android Studio, the app doesn't run, but lines of log are running at the ADB window (Android monitor). Feels like it's running in the background.

The only way to launch my app and track it is to click the Debug button, set the Breakpoint, run the app manually, click the Debug button again. But I don't want to Debug! 
P.S. Sorry for that bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop the debugging process and rebuild your project. It works for me. Try it.